# Formula to rate an item based on its performance

Tags: average, percentages, means

For an item i, I have a low price estimation L, an high price estimation H and the price realized P. I need to figure out some kind of numeric indicator showing the performance of an item in regards to its estimations. 
Examples:
- an item that has  P=100 when L=40 and H=90 should have a very good score because it outperforms H
- an item with P=80 when L=40 and H=90 should have a good score because P is close to 90

- an item with P=65 when L=40 and H=90 should have an average score because P is right at the mean
- an item with P=45 when L=40 and H=90 should have a low score because P is close to L
- an item with P=30 when L=40 and H=90 should have a very low score because P underperforms L.

What formula would you apply to compute such a score ?

Comment: Formulas with this specification can be very many. For example, simply taking $P/L + P/H$ yields something that fits the description; in particular, scores below 1 are taken to be bad scores, between 1 and 2 they're average, and above 2 they're good. Is there any particular property this measure should have? Linearity, continuity...

Comment: @NikiDiGiano sorry I havent done math in a long time, I think linearity and continuity would be good specs indeed

Comment: The simplest formula would be $P-L$, although you can also make it dependent on $H$ by making it $\frac{P-L}{H}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function of the form:
$$
S = \frac{P - L}{H - L}
$$
Is very simple to calculate and plot, as well as continuous and (affine) linear; its plot against $P$ is just a straight line. Bad scores are negative, average scores are in the range $[0, 1]$, while good scores are above $1$. In particular, the score of the mean is always $0.5$.

If you want a different value (maybe you want the average range to be from $0$ to $\alpha$) it is sufficient to multiply the right hand side by $\alpha$.

The very first formula I mentioned is:
$$
S = \frac PH + \frac PL
$$
This function happens to be a linear function of $P$, always positive, increasing in $P$ and continuous. However, the mean has score $1 + (\frac H{2L} + \frac L{2H})$ so comparing items belonging to different price ranges will be more difficult.